# How do I properly rotate these houses?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am using C++, OpenGL and glut. I am trying to make 5 houses that are rotated properly like this:

[image]

However, whenever I try to implement the `glRotatef` function, I seem to not be able to either get the proper coordinates or something is off somewhere in my code. Furthermore, I set the background color to white but it's still all black, how come? For now I have the houses set to white to counter this for now. Here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

typedef int vert2D[2]; 

void initialize()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 

    glLoadIdentity(); 
    gluOrtho2D(10.0, 215.0, 0.0, 250.0);  

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void drawHouse(vert2D* sq, vert2D* tri)
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2iv(sq[0]);
    glVertex2iv(sq[1]);
    glVertex2iv(sq[2]);
    glVertex2iv(sq[3]);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2iv(tri[0]);
    glVertex2iv(tri[1]);
    glVertex2iv(tri[2]);
    glEnd();
}

void render()
{
    vert2D sqPts[4] = { {115, 150}, {115, 125}, {100,125}, {100,150} };
    vert2D triPts[3] = { {120, 150}, {95,150}, {108,160} };

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    drawHouse(sqPts, triPts);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glRotatef(-10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
    drawHouse(sqPts, triPts); 
    glTranslatef(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

    glRotatef(-10.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    drawHouse(sqPts, triPts);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glRotatef(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
    drawHouse(sqPts, triPts); 
    glTranslatef(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 

    glRotatef(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
    drawHouse(sqPts, triPts); 
    glPopMatrix(); 

    glFlush(); 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);           
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); 
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480); 
    glutCreateWindow("TestMeOut"); 

    initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(render); 

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's answer the simpler question of why your background is still black, first:
You simply never `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` the color buffer. You tell OpenGL "hey, the next time I call glClear with (at least) the GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, I want the color buffer to be cleared to white." but you never actually clear the buffer.

Now, onto how we can draw the houses with their correct locations and orientations:

You should first start by defining your house's vertices in a sensible local coordinate system/frame that is suitable for transforming them in further steps. Currently, with how you define your house's vertices, it is hard to do any transformations on those (mainly because linear transformations like rotation are always relative to the coordinate system's origin).

So, let's change that. Let's define the origin (0, 0) for your house to be the center of the bottom/base line of the house. And let's also define that your house's quad has a side length of 10 "units":

```
vert2D sqPts[4] = {
    {-5, 0}, // <- bottom left
    { 5, 0}, // <- bottom right
    { 5,10}, // <- top right
    {-5,10}  // <- top left
};
```

Now, for the roof of the house, we assume the same coordinate system (with (0, 0) being the center of the house's base/bottom line), so we start at Y=10:

```
vert2D triPts[3] = {
    {-6, 10}, // <- left
    { 6, 10}, // <- right
    { 0, 12}  // <- top
};
```

Next, we need to define where (0, 0) should be in our "world", so to speak. One definition could be: (0, 0) should be the center of the bottom of the viewport/screen and the viewport should have a length of 100 "units". Right now, we don't care about a correct aspect ratio when the viewport's width does not equal the viewport's height. This can be added later.

Starting from the clip space coordinate system, we can transform this clip space into our own "world space" by using these transformations:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0, -1.0, 0.0); // <- move the origin down to the bottom of the viewport
glScalef(1.0 / 50.0, 1.0 / 50.0, 1.0); // <- "scale down" the clip space to cover more space in the viewport
```

Now, the above part is essentially what `gluOrtho2D()` does as well, but highlighting the actual coordinate system transformation steps is useful here.

Now that we defined our house's local coordinate system and our "world" coordinate system, we can rotate and translate the world coordinate system such that the houses appear at their correct locations and orientations in our world.

In order to draw 5 houses, we just use a for-loop:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
for (int i = -2; i <= 2; i++) { // <- 5 steps
  glPushMatrix();
  glRotatef(i * 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glTranslatef(0.0, 50.0, 0.0);
  drawHouse(sqPts, triPts);
  glPopMatrix();
}
```

So, starting from our world coordinate system, we transform it by rotating the appropriate amount around its origin (0, 0) for the house with index `i` to have the correct rotation, and then translate the coordinate system by 50 units along its (now rotated) Y axis.

These two transformations will now result in a house to be drawn at the desired location. So, repeat that 5 times in total with differing rotation angles, and you're done.